# How to create auto-increment column that starts with zero?

Tags: postgresql

I want to have a table with column "SID" that starts with 0.

I tried

```sql
CREATE TABLE security (
    SID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 0 INCREMENT BY 2),
);
```

But I got an error
 `RESTART value (0) cannot be less than MINVALUE (1)`

Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: Then add `minvalue 0` to the options.

Comment: SID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 0 INCREMENT BY 2 MINVALUE 0)